# Multitab pages in excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a spread sheet with two worksheets called "Page 1" and "Page 2". I also have a user form with a multipage control which contains two tabs named: Page 1 and Page 2 (like the worksheets). My goal is to be able to click the tab named "Page 1" and VBA to instantly display the content of the worksheet called "Page 1" or the tab named "Page 2" and VBA to instantly display the content of the worksheet called "Page 2". I've done a lot of research on Google and there doesn't seem to be a way of doing what I described above. I also recorded a macro but I don't think it is possible assign it to the Page 1, Page 2 tabs (please see below).Would you have any suggestions? I appreciate your help, thanks.

```
 Sub Macro3()
 Sheets("Page 1").Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: What exctly do you mean by "VBA to instantly display the content of the worksheet called "Page 1"" ? the worksheet that will be selected will be "Page 1" ? or you want to import the entire contents of the worksheets in to a user_form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code below inside the `User_Form` module, inside your `MultiPage` object, in the `Change` event.

You want to `Activate` the worksheet according to your `SelectedItem.Caption` (and not `.Name`)

**Code**

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

    ' activate the sheet according to the caption of the multi-page selected item
    Worksheets(MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption).Activate

End Sub
```

*Multi-Page Object screen-shot*:

[image]

---

**Edit 1**: To add a screen-shot to your post:

[image]

Comment: @Elena see the creen-shot under **Edit 1**

Comment: If your `Worksheet.Name` doesn't match, you will get an error. Let's say you select "Page 1" , but your worksheet name is "Page 1" with a space in between, this will result with an error. Or, you can check if the `Worksheet.name` exists in the workbook, by adding a loop.

Comment: @Elena you should open a new post, describe what you want (new requests), add you modified and updated code, this will allow other users (besides mt) to help you. Otherwise, posts here will never get closed.